# Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Which one of the first order predicate calculus statements given below correctly expresses the following English statement?

"Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened".

1. $∀x[(tiger(x) ∧ lion(x)) → \{(hungry(x) ∨ threatened(x)) → attacks(x)\}]$
2. $∀x[(tiger(x) ∨ lion(x)) → \{(hungry(x) ∨ threatened(x)) ∧ attacks(x)\}]$
3. $∀x[(tiger(x) ∨ lion(x)) → \{attacks(x) → (hungry(x) ∨ threatened(x))\}]$
4. $∀x[(tiger(x) ∨ lion(x)) → \{(hungry(x) ∨ threatened(x)) → attacks(x)\}]$

---

My attempt :

The statement "Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened" means that if an animal is either tiger or lion at the same time.

"Tigers or lions if they are hungry or threatened then attacked "

So, option $(4)$ is correct.

> Can you explain in English statements for each option?

Comment: Your attempt is correct, what's stopping you from completing the rest yourself?

Comment: Option $(1)$ means tiger and lions attacked at the same time when they are hungry or threatened at same time ?

Comment: what are meaning of options $(3)$ and $(2)$?

Comment: Yeah, I understood that right after I wrote the comment, so see if my answer below explains it clearly enough for you to understand.

Comment: (1) Says that any $x$ that is both a tiger & a lion attacks if it is either hungry or threatened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1$. [Tigons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigon) and [ligers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liger) attack if they are hungry or threatened

$2$. Tigers and lions are always hungry or threatened and always attack

$3$. Tigers and lions are hungry or threatened if they attack

$4$. Tigers and lions attack if they are hungry or threatened

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: You're welcome :)

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: I understand that it is rather confusing, as you translate "$\vee$" into "and", but this is how you'd express those statements in a "natural language" (it just wouldn't sound right if you used "or").

Comment: I think 1. is funny but is wrong. A tigon is neither a tiger nor a lion (that is why it is called tigon). the same is true for ligers. So sentence 1. means: "if something is a tiger and a lion (which is not possible), then ..."

Comment: @miracle173: Your **personal** biological opinion (`"that is why it is called a tigon"???`) is not a good enough reason to down-vote the answer!!! First of all, because clearly you have understood my interpretation of Tigon and Liger, and second, because your statement about the biological nature of these two animals is a matter of opinion in the good case, and wrong in the bad case (and `"that is why it is called a tigon"` is by no means a proof of this statement being true)!!! Please revoke it unless you have a good enough explanation for this action.

Comment: @barakmanos, AFAIK :$\text{your every statement is correct, in fact I want to accept your answer also if it possible. Thanks for nice statements :)}$.

Comment: @barak manos: 1)Yes, the downvote is from me. 2) It is up to me to decide if a reason is good enough for a downvote and not to you to decide this. 3) It is not my "personal biological opinion" but it follows from wikis definition of [hybrid speciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_speciation) that these are  new species. 4) $\land$ is the intersection of two classes and using these hybrid species makes this less clear and so I do not like it

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: Thank you, but you can only accept one answer, and if there are a few correct answers then you should accept the one you think is best, so I trust your decision. My problem is with "wise-guys" like the one above who down-vote me with no good reason. If your a human, does that mean you're not a primate? Every liger is a lion, just as every lion is a cat.

Comment: @miracle173: Your statement of a liger not being a lion is simply false, that is why you should revoke your vote! Every liger is a lion just as every lion is a cat (and just as every human is a primate). That is the exact definition, and your definition is wrong!!!

Comment: @barakmanos, I accepted your answer as best, since people are giving unnecessary "downvote" but not explanation.:)

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: Thank you :) But feel free to accept the best answer regardless of other users voting. The other answer looks pretty good, so if you think it's better then accept it instead. If you think they're the same, then choose the one that was given first.

Comment: I accepted this answer as best and I'm giving thanks to @BrianO for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

In English, "and" can be moved into the antecedent of a conditional when the logical connective that renders the statement is really "or". It's short for the conjunction of two conditionals.

For example, given $\forall x(Boy(x)\to Happy(x))$ ("[all] boys are happy") and $\forall x(Girl(x)\to Happy(x))$ ("[all] girls are happy"), we 
have $\forall x(Boy(x)\to Happy(x)) \land \forall x(Girl(x)\to Happy(x))$, which can be said as "all boys and all girls are happy", or just "[all]boys and girls are happy". Note, though, that the logical equivalence used is:
$$
((p\to r)\land (q\to r))\iff ((p\lor q)\to r).
$$
The formula equivalent to the conjunction of the statements about girls and boys is: $\forall x((Boy(x)\lor Girl(x))\to Happy(x))$.

1. means: Anything $x$ that is both a tiger and a lion attacks if it is either hungry or threatened.
2. All lions and tigers are hungry or threatened, and attacks. Or: every lion or tiger is hungry or threatened, and attacks.
3. Every lion or tiger that attacks is hungry or threatened.
4. Every lion or tiger that is hungry or threatened, attacks. Or: lions and tigers attack when hungry or threatened.

I see that I wrote "lions and tigers", not "tigers and lions". Fortunately, they're equivalent! I couldn't help it: because of the Wizard of Oz ("Lions and tigers and bears!") that's more idiomatic. Similarly, "it's raining cats and dogs!", but it never rains dogs and cats :)

Comment: $∀x(Happy(x)→(Boy(x)∧Girl(x)))$ is equivalent to "$\text{all happy people are boy and girl}$"?
and $∀x((Boy(x)∧Girl(x))→Happy(x))$ is equivalent to $\text{all people are happy if they are boy and girl}$?

Comment: $\text{Thanks for very nice explanation.}$

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Comment: Re your first comment question: the first says, as you have it, "every happy person is both a boy and a girl" (!). The second one says that "anyone who is both a boy and a girl is happy" - which may or may not be true :)

Comment: Same as $\text{Tigers and lions}$?.

Comment: Is what the same as tigers and lions?